# How to attach a logger to that of nodemailer SMTPTransport class

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Need to add a custom winston logger to the SMTPTransport transport class but after attaching the logger does not perform any error logging function at all.

Following is an excerpt from SMTPTransport class in nodejs nodemailer util

```
class SMTPTransport extends EventEmitter {
...
    this.logger = shared.getLogger(this.options, {
            component: this.options.component || 'smtp-transport'
    });
...
send(mail, callback) {
....
               connection.send(envelope, mail.message.createReadStream(), (err, info) => {
                ...
                try {
                    return callback(null, info);
                } catch (E) {
                    this.logger.error(
                        {
                            err: E,
                            tnx: 'callback'
                        },
                        'Callback error for %s: %s',
                        messageId,
                        E.message
                    );
                }
            });
```

Attempts to override like the following example do not initiate any error logging.

In the following example this logger logs everything except exceptions from inside the send function shown above:

```
    winston.loggers.add('logger', {
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.Console)({
                level: logLevel,
                colorize: true,
                handleExceptions: true,
                humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
                showLevel: true,
                timestamp: showCliLogPrefix,
                stderrLevels: []
            }),
            options
        ]
    });
    var nodeMailer = require(<path to nodeMailer>)
    nodeMailer .logger = logger
```

So how to attach this winston logger to nodeMailer logger?